# Is it possible to software break a Native Client application in GDB and continue execution?

Tags: gdb, google-nativeclient

Does anyone have any experience of using the Windows Native Client debugger as described  [here](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/how-tos/debuggingtips/debugging-untrusted-code-with-a-special-gdb-build-on-windows) to debug a Native Client application?

I'm trying to fire a software breakpoint or exception in the application code which would halt the attached and running GDB at the source line it was fired from and be able to continue execution.

I can do this by creating an illegal address exception, eg:

```
#define SOFTBREAK { int *p=0; p=0; }
```

which does break into the debugger where ever the define is used:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000c00209ba2 in CTestTestList::Init (this=0xfe55d080) at ../testlist.cpp:1242
1242    in ../testlist.cpp
```

however i can't seem to continue execution using the *jump* command to skip the break line, (either using the next source line or assembly address). Do i need to acknowledge or clear the segmentation fault before continuing?

Does anyone know if its possible to continiue exectuion using the illegal address exception? Or is there a different method that could be used, for example, raising a software exception, (EXC_SOFTWARE)?
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

(Btw, this is my first post to stack overflow so apologises if i've not followed any etiquette with this post.)

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I usually use an infinite loop for the same purpose.

```
volatile int var = 1;
while (var);
```

Then I change corresponding register value in debugger.

```
set $rax = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback 'Ha'.
That is very useful and it does work for me.

However, (just in case others are following this), it seems that in the version of GDB i'm using 'var' is a keyword and so i had to use a different name. Also as 'var' is marked volatile it will be read from memory every loop iteration and so i used:
    set myVar = 0
instead.

Thanks again for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__asm__("int3");` with winGDB, as detailed [here](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.com/2010/05/breakpoints-in-gdb-using-int3.html)

[~Main](http://mainroach.blogspot.com)

Comment: int 3 was one of the first things i tried but this violates Native Client safety rules so the NaCl plugin fails to load the application, (VALIDATION FAILED reported in NACLLOG).

(Not sure if its possible to disable this check though?)

Thanks for the response though Colt.